# Getting the value from an array from a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Coming from Python, I could easily do `array[0][0]`, but doesn't seem like it in C#.

When I try to fetch data from my MySQL database, it gives me a 2D array, hence the need to use a 2D array.

Array looks like this:

```
[[hello], [world]]
```

I'd like to just fetch the string "hello". How would I manage that?

Comment: try array[0, 0]

Comment: Are you using a reader which enumerates through the rows?  Then the second dimensions are the columns.  It is probably easier to use a MySQL DataAdapter which put the results into a DataTable.  From the Data Table you can then use two dimensions to access data.  Normally you do not care about a row number instead you filter for the data from the column contents and do not care about the row number.

Comment: Please post code showing how you get the data, because it doesn't normally just come in a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
string value = array[0,0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
   var array= new String[,] {{"Hello","World"}};
   string value=array[0,0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access multidimensional arrays like this:

```
int val = a[2,3];
```

The above statement takes 4th element from the 3rd row of the array.

In your case it would be:

```
string val = a[0,0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward: `arrray[0, 0]`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)